# Replacing unicode character with similar character from standard utf-8 english

Tags: python, mysql, unicode

I was building a database with python/mysql by parsing a data file.
At a point, the file contained the character '`р`'. When the mysql query gets that as input, it breaks.

So the problem is the above is not standard English character "`p`"

if you try `json.dumps('р')`, you'll find it outputs `'\u0440'`

Is there a way to detect the encoding and replace with something similar from standard utf-8 English ? I can't manually replace all `р` with `p` as there are lots of other Unicode characters as well.

Beating my head right now. Pls throw some light or hint.

Comment: Note: the character is Unicode, so encoded also in UTF-8. Just not what many people would expect. But this is a different problem. You see table of easy confusable characters. Your character is `CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ER`, so valid in many context, but probably not ideal as identifier (or better if one user choose it, you should disallow same username but with Latin script p). So it depends on purpose. Check https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/confusables.jsp and a lot of libraries which may help you

Comment: is there a solution to replace such occurrences with standard english characters?

Comment: In general no. BTW how do you handle non Latin characters? Do you allow them? And what about when a word is all in a different script? And "Standard English Characters" have many more characters than people have usually in mind. In any case, the bug is elsewhere. mysql support Unicode, so check your mysql client settings (wrong locale?)

Comment: @SubrataRabidas - I would try to get the data that is used for the "confusables" link, then find the smallest Unicode value for each source character -- it is very likely to be an ordinary English letter.

Comment: thats smart, thanks @RickJames